# Availability of parameter "upperLayerIndication-r15"

Tags: android, mobile, lte, 4g, 5g

In 4G LTE, each cell broadcasts a parameter called `upperLayerIndication-r15`, which can be used by the network operator to indicate that the 5G NR service is available in that cell (see for example [here](https://moniem-tech.com/2021/02/12/does-5g-icon-on-your-phone-mean-real-5g/)). This parameter is part of the [system information](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/LTE-MIB-SIB-system-information-blocks.html), and more specifically appears in SIB 2. Mobile terminals in idle mode read this parameter, along with the rest of system information.

I have not found this parameter in [Android's API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference). Is it available to applications, perhaps with a different name?